# jQuery DatePicker conflicting with "defaultValue"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I wrote a simple script that will highlight input fields and textarea when their values have changed from default value (on page load)

Using "defaultValue" actually works fantastic.

$('input[type=text], textarea').on('change', function() {

```
    if($(this).prop("defaultValue") != $(this).val()) {
        $(this).addClass('changed');    
    }
    else
        $(this).removeClass('changed');
```

});

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with input[type=text] when you turn it into jQuery Ui date picker.  Been looking at this for hours, but I'm lost...!

Thanks,

Comment: it works fine, look here plz [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/a79xsbho/2/)

Comment: @Baximilian Thanks.  You made me look into the issue more.  I realize it's the date mask script that's causing conflict.